# How can I add a toggle bar without distrubting original nav bar layout?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm building a nav bar using bootstrap which has my name on the left and the links on the right. The layout was fine until I added the toggle button. It now shows my name on the left and the links right by it rather than being on the right (when the page is expanded). When the page is minimized it looks fine. How can I fix this?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h1 class="text-white"> Aiya Siddig</h1>

    <button class = "navbar-toggler" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#collapse_target">
      <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon" ></span>
    </button>
    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "collapse_target">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"> About Me </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html"> Portfolio </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
       </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap class [justify-content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) with `flex-end` in your `collapse` `navbar` to make sure your links are always to the `right` on bigger `screen` and `responsive` as well.

**Live Working Demo:**

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h1 class="text-white"> Aiya Siddig</h1>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_target">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapse_target">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html"> About Me </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html"> Portfolio </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Now when I click on the toggle bar it doesnt open up the links

Comment: @AiyaSiddig You are welcome. Glad to have helped. Happy coding :)